# Calling two methods of the same object in C# - chain like syntax

Tags: c#, methods, syntax

Cosidering I can't change class ReadTheFile, is there a way how to "chain" instance methods so I don't have to reference myObject multiple times? I am looking for something like 
    `myObject.Read().Open(param1);`

I can write `myObject.Open(param1).Read()`; which compiles however Read() is not executed.

//`myObject.Open(param1).Read()`; does execute but it's executed as StreamReader method not ReadTheFile method. Overlooked VS help...

```
class TestT211
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myObject = new ReadTheFile();

        myObject.Read(myObject.Open(@"C:\file.txt"));          
    } 
}

public class ReadTheFile
{
    private int _lineCounter = 0;
    private string _lineOfText;

    public StreamReader Open(string path)
    {
        return new StreamReader(path);
    }

    public void Read(StreamReader sr)
    {
        while ((_lineOfText = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(_lineOfText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you want to build fluent API...

Comment: The Read() isn't calling the method on the ReadTheFile as you expect - instead it's calling a method on StreamReader. The Fluent syntax (which is what you're trying to get with chained method calls) usually has methods returning the object they're called on.

Comment: You could write builder for that with private StreamReader assigned on Open() and check if its null on Read().

Comment: If you can't change `ReadTheFile`, this is impossible.

Comment: Fluent syntax is definitely the thing I am looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using simple builder (it's overkill) but you could achive what you want:

```
 class TestT211
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileReaderBuilder.New.Open(@"C:\file.txt").Read();
    }
}

public class ReadTheFile
{
    private int _lineCounter = 0;
    private string _lineOfText;

    public StreamReader Open(string path)
    {
        return new StreamReader(path);
    }

    public void Read(StreamReader sr)
    {
        while ((_lineOfText = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_lineOfText);
        }
    }
}

public class FileReaderBuilder
{
    private readonly ReadTheFile _file;

    private StreamReader _streamReader;

    private FileReaderBuilder()
    {
        _file = new ReadTheFile();
    }

    public FileReaderBuilder Open(string path)
    {
         _streamReader = _file.Open(path);

        return this;
    }

    public FileReaderBuilder Read()
    {
        if (_streamReader == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_streamReader));
        }

        _file.Read(_streamReader);

        return this;
    }

    public static FileReaderBuilder New => new FileReaderBuilder();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a syntax like a Fluent API you need to change some point of your class. First you need to have Open return the current instance and then use that instance to call Read. But this assumes that you keep the StreamReader as an internal variable of the class

```
public class ReadTheFile : IDisposable
{
    private int _lineCounter = 0;
    private string _lineOfText;
    private StreamReader _sr = null;

    public ReadTheFile Open(string path)
    {
        _sr = new StreamReader(path);
        return this;
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        if(_sr == null) return;

        while ((_lineOfText = _sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(_lineOfText);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) 
        {
            if(_sr != null) 
            {
               _sr.Close();
               _sr = null;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

and now you can write

```
 using(ReadTheFile myObject = new ReadTheFile())
      myObject.Open(@"C:\file.txt").Read();
```

Notice that having a StreamReader between your internal variables requires you to implement the IDisposable interface to properly close and dispose the Stream

Comment: Added +1 since this is better solution, but I assumed he cannot modifie ReadTheFile object.

Comment: @LukaszBalazy yes correct. I have not aimed to show a full FluentAPI implementation. Just how to fix its current code to achieve the syntax required

Comment: AFAiK you don't have to assign null to _sr variable since if value is not initialized it's already null.

Comment: Since I can't touch ReadTheFile this won't work for me, but I still see this helpful.

Comment: You're also correct about this. But give me some space on my habits. I'm used to this syntax. It gives me a little comfort when I re-read my code. Old people like me are stubborn

Comment: @Steve Please take no offense I'm always keen to learn new perspectives and if you think it's more readable with = null I'll think about that. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add more functionality to class without access to it, you can use extensions. For example to use ReadTheFile to read StreamReader.

```
public static class StreamReaderExtension
{
    public static StreamReader ReadEx(this StreamReader sr)
    {
        var readTheFile = new ReadTheFile();
        readTheFile.Read(sr);
        return sr;
    }
}
```

and than call it with

```
myObject.Open(@"C:\file.txt").ReadEx();
```

You can add more methods, but cannot override the instance ones so you have to create a new name or new signature.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this.